# MS Access SQL Pass Through Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to rebuild an MS Access (O365 version) Pass through query into an MS SQL query (Server Management Studio version 15.0.18118.0) but i'm getting stuck on one piece of MS Access SQL.  It's at the line seen below "A.X_PAGER_CO_ID = P.ROW_ID(+)".  I am not sure what or how the (+) works.  When I update this for MS SQL server it gives me a error because of the (+), when I take this out.  My data set is different.  I do need to return the same data set in MS SQL Server as seen WITH the (+) in MS Access

With (+) I see this data set (does not work in SQL Server):

```
EMPLOYEEID|X_PAGER_CO_ID|ROW_ID   |PhoneNum
1-39T1L0  |1-3A3Z2E     |1-3A3Z2E |555-555-5555
1-39T1L0  |             |         |777-777-7777
1-39T1L0  |             |         |888-888-8888
1-39T1L0  |1-N0-3       |1-N0-3   |+AlphanumericPager 0000000000000 00000
```

With OUT (+) I see this data set (Does work in SQL Server):

```
EMPLOYEEID|X_PAGER_CO_ID|ROW_ID   |PhoneNum
1-39T1L0  |1-3A3Z2E     |1-3A3Z2E |555-555-5555
1-39T1L0  |1-N0-3       |1-N0-3   |+AlphanumericPager 0000000000000 00000
```

```
A.PER_ID As EmployeeID,
A.X_PAGER_CO_ID,
P.ROW_ID,

  A.ADDR As PhoneNumber,
  A.COMM_MEDIUM_CD As DeviceType,
  A.X_ACTIVE_FLG As ActiveFlag,
  P.NAME As PagerCompanyName,
  P.PAGE_PH_NUM As PagerCompanyModem,
  P.X_SUPPORT_PH_NUM As PagerCompanySupport,
  A.X_PIN As PIN
FROM 
  xTrack.S_PER_COMM_ADDR A,
  xTrack.S_PAGER_COMPANY P
WHERE
  A.X_PAGER_CO_ID = P.ROW_ID(+) and
  A.PER_ID IN (SELECT 
                         E.PAR_ROW_ID 
                       FROM
                         xTrack.S_EMP_PER E,
                         xTrack.S_CONTACT C,
                         xTrack.S_BU SB,
                         xTrack.S_POSTN SP
                      WHERE
                         E.PAR_ROW_ID = C.PAR_ROW_ID AND
                         SP.BU_ID = SB.ROW_ID AND
                         C.PR_HELD_POSTN_ID = SP.PAR_ROW_ID)

AND A.PER_ID = '1-39T1L0'
```

Answer (score 0):

that expression P.ROW(+) can't work in access and never could have. So, I would go back to the original query - that simply does not make sense. I suspect that some kind of user defined function (UDF()) was being used in the original sql. So that is not actually a column name, but some kind of function.

You can fire up access and try any query with COLUMNNAME(+) and it will fail. So, you can't migrate something that don't work in Access. And until such time figure out what the original access sql looked like, then I am afraid your attempt at recreating the same query in SQL server will also fail.

That expression is not valid SQL in Access, so the issue is in the translation of the original Access sql - it is simply wrong or incorrect.

It is possible that this was the column name so you would/should use:

P.[ROW(+)]

In other words, for columns with spaces, funny characters, and reserved words (like "date" or "name" as a column name in access). Such reserved words thus need a set of [] surrounding the column name. I would look at the table design - see if there is a column named as such.

If yes, then try [] around the column name. If the column name does not exist, then that sql simply could not have worked in Access.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  As was able to recreate the data sets by doing left joins.  I am not the originator of this original Access DB or the wrote the SQL that was doing the Pass Through to a SQL Server DB.  It works fine in Access (even using the +).  

But that's a challenge for another day.  I do appreciate you taking the time to help.